# AutoCAD .net : Check is font file missing

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

#### Achievement

Hi! In AutoCAD, there's a yellow icon displayed if the font is missing.

[image]

I'm working on AutoCAD .net api in C#. I want to check if there's any font file missing in AutoCAD.

#### Approaches

My idea to approach this is:

1. Implement a method `checkIsFontFileMissing` with a `TextStyleTableRecord` input, it returns a `boolean` indicates that if the font file of this text style is missing.(missing icon is shown in AutoCAD)
2. Iterate all text style and check them with `checkIsFontFileMissing`

something like below:

```cs
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using AcadApplication = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;

[CommandMethod("TT")]
public void TT()
{
    Document doc = AcadApplication.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database database = doc.Database;
    Editor editor = doc.Editor;
    using (var tr = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        var textStyleTbl = database.TextStyleTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as TextStyleTable;
        foreach (ObjectId objId in textStyleTbl)
        {
            var textStyle = objId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as TextStyleTableRecord;

            checkIsFontFileMissing(textStyle);
        }
    }
}
```

for `checkIsFontFileMissing`:

1. if any of `FileName` / `BigFontFileName` not exists, return true(some file missing)
2. only if both of `FileName` / `BigFontFileName` exist, return false(all file not missing)
3. if `FileName` / `BigFontFileName` is empty string, regard it as not missing.

My idea is to find font file from all paths in support search path in AutoCAD. it looks like:

```cs
bool checkIsFontFileMissing(TextStyleTableRecord textStyle)
{
    //get all support search path in AutoCAD
    object acadObject = AcadApplication.AcadApplication;
    object preferences = acadObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Preferences", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, acadObject, null);
    object files = preferences.GetType().InvokeMember("Files", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, preferences, null);
    string supportPathStr = (string)files.GetType().InvokeMember("SupportPath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, files, null);
    string[] supportPaths = supportPathStr.Split(';');

    //access file name of font
    string fontFile = textStyle.FileName;
    string bigFontFile = textStyle.BigFontFileName;

    //try to find font file in all support search path
    bool isFontFileMissing = fontFile == "" ? false : true;
    bool isBigFontFileMissing = bigFontFile == "" ? false : true;
    foreach (string supportPath in supportPaths)
    {
        string fontFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(supportPath, fontFile);
        string bigFontFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(supportPath, bigFontFile);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fontFilePath)) isFontFileMissing = false;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(bigFontFilePath)) isBigFontFileMissing = false;
    }

    return isFontFileMissing || isBigFontFileMissing;
}
```

#### Problems

1. most of `FileName` property contains ".shx" at the end. but some of them do not. for example we have **txt.shx** in some path, but `FileName` property return **txt** (not **txt.shx**), so it's unable to find a file in `checkIsFontFileMissing`
2. some files that can't be found from all paths, but shown not missing in AutoCAD. for example I have a font **stylu.ttf** , this file can't be found from all paths, but shown not missing in AutoCAD. is it because there are some built-in font or something?

In summary, my approach seems not to be a good one. is there a better approach to do this? Any suggestion is really appreciated!